# W3C validation for complete site

Tags: w3c-validation

I am working on a project where I have to validate the complete site, which has around 150 pages, through W3C Markup Validation. Is there a way to check W3C Markup Validation of an entire website?

Comment: The most up-to-date answer (in 2021) is this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926694/8932080 btw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **W3C doesn't offer this** on w3.org.

http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-batchvalidation

But you can use this tool and **check "Validate entire site"**: (Also w3.org refers to this site!)

- http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/

But you have a **limit of 100 URLs** to validate and will get this message when you reach 100 URLs:

*`Batch validation is limited to 100 URLs at one time. The remaining URLs were not checked.`*

Also there's a **limit of errors displayed** for **each url**.

Comment: That htmlhelp site is super out of date and completely not relevant to the main w3 validator

Comment: @MattFletcher At the time of writing this answer in 2012, ~5.5 years ago, the help page of w3.org, I've referred to in my answer, linked to the htmlhelp.com website (see [archive.org snapshot from Jan 19 '12](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119115514/http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html)). Instead of down-voting you could've simply suggested an edit to bring the answer up-to-date.

Answer (score 7):

The WDG offers two free solutions:

1. [Validate entire site](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/) (select 'validate entire site')
2. [Validate multiple URLs](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/batch.html.en) (batch)

Comment: FYI the WDG validator does not support HTML5.

Comment: W3C Validator Suite service was discontinued and the source code was open sourced here: https://github.com/w3c/validator-suite/ It doesn't seem to be maintained by anyone though, so the first part of the answer is a dead-end right now.

Comment: Limited to 100 pages; doesn't solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the validator yourself.  As of 2018, W3C are using v.Nu for their validator, the code is at https://github.com/validator/validator/releases/latest and usage instructions are at https://validator.github.io/validator/#usage

For example, the following command will run it on all `html` files under the `public_html` directory:

```
java -jar vnu.jar --skip-non-html public_html
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this tool bulk w3c html validator to validate my entire website

http://www.bulkseotools.com/bulk-w3c-validator.php

This tool uses W3c validator engine, you can check 500 urls at once.

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://sitevalidator.com; I think it would be helpful to you.

Comment: Unfortunately in a twist of fate that site is now invalid (certificate issue).

Comment: The certificate issue must have been a temporary issue, the link works now.

Answer (score 1):

I made this java app (Windows installer) in my spare time because I needed it at work:
https://gsoft.no/validator. It's free.

It uses either https://validator.w3.org/ or v.Nu running locally to validate an entire site.

It crawls a website and in the end makes a report with validator-links to all pages with warnings or errors. Because it crawls, all pages to be validated must be linked.

By running v.Nu locally you can validate an internal site (e.g. an intranet)  which is not available online and therefore cannot be validated by online  validators (unless you post the entire content of each page).

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).