# Want to know the way to pass my entire website w3c validation using some hacks or scripts (php/javascript/xml).

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I am working on a projects, Projects contain more than 100 pages. 
fixed all pages as per w3c guidelines is really a time taken process. 
There is any alternative or w3c hacks which i can used on header or somewhere to validate all pages.

I don't to want to know the way to check these pages w3c validate or not,
i just want to know the way to pass my entire website w3c validation using some hacks or scripts (php/javascript/xml).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [W3C validation for complete site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922014/w3c-validation-for-complete-site)

Comment: Do you want to show invalid pages as a valid page without fix it?

Comment: What's the point of validation if you're just going to pretend your markup is valid?

Comment: i want to know there is any scripts or something which i can used instead of fixes all the pages one by one.

Comment: I do not understand, if you want your pages follow the guidelines w3c you'll have to adjust your code to them. There are no shortcuts, or you do or not, nor is it mandatory

Answer (score 0):

The process of validation ensures that a webpage is future proofed and will work in other versions of a web browser. It will also (to a certain extent) allow you to debug your work. For further reasons to validate see https://validator.w3.org/docs/why.html#why_pros. It is not something you *have* to do. So, rather than *hack* the validator just don't validate. Not validating doesn't mean that your website is broken and won't work it just means that your website might use outdated tags or doesn't follow what is considered to be best practise.